# Patternsearch discrete variables

Tags: matlab, optimization

I want to optimize a multi-variable function with the `patternsearch` function in MATLAB. The function requires a lower and upper boundary and looks within the boundaries in a continuous domain.

I however have a discrete set of values in an excel file and would like the algorithm to search within this discrete domain instead of in the continuous domain.

Is this possible with `patternsearch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best optimization tool for this is the **Genetic Algorithm**. This optimization tool comes with Matlab's global optimization toolbox and allows for optimization of both continuous and discrete variables at the same time.

In the genetic algorithm variables that are integers have to be declared as such. Non-declared variables are continuous by default.

Check the Global Optimization Toolbox guide for information on how it works: http://it.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/gads/gads_tb.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand correctly your question but if you have a (discret and finite) set of values, why don't you compute the function's value at these points and return the minium?

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. That is not what `patternsearch` is intended for. Optimization techniques for discrete and continuous search spaces are quite expectedly different.

If you're looking for an approximate answer however, it is possible to use `spline`, `polyfit`, etc. to arrive at an approximate continuous function for your data and then apply `patternsearch` on it.

If you provide greater detail about your problem, I or someone else may be able to suggest a more suitable way of working with your data.